# Is it possible to run two functions (one running FastAPI - ASGI, and one running Flask - WSGI), in one Azure function App?

Tags: python, azure-functions

Im trying testing if its possible to run two functions in one Azure function app one running FastAPI and the other one running Flask.

I tried to specify a different route for each `function.json` file but to no avail.

```
# FastAPI function.json
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
        {
        "authLevel": "anonymous",
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "name": "req",
        "methods": [
            "get",
            "post",
            "patch",
            "delete"
        ],
        "route": "/api/{*route}"
        },
        {
        "type": "http",
        "direction": "out",
        "name": "$return"
        }
    ]
}

# __init__.py
import logging
import azure.functions as func

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/api/hello/")
async def hello():
return {'message': 'Hello World!'}

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:

    return func.AsgiMiddleware(app).handle(req, context)
```

and

```
# Flask function.json
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
        {
        "authLevel": "anonymous",
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "name": "req",
        "methods": [
            "get",
            "post",
            "patch",
            "delete"
        ],
        "route": "/flask/{*route}"
        },
        {
        "type": "http",
        "direction": "out",
        "name": "$return"
        }
    ]
}

#__init__.py
import logging
import azure.functions as func

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/home/")
def home():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    
    return func.WsgiMiddleware(app.wsgi_app).handle(req, context)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you deploy using GitHub, you can run two functions in one Azure function app.

- To do this push the required code in a GitHub repository.
- Then in the azure function go to the **development center** section.
- Then select source as GitHub it will ask you to login and for
  permissions.
- After granting them select the repository (the repository must be
  private) and then select branch then click save.
- Refresh the function app and you will see the triggers in the
  function section

refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment#:%7E:text=1%20In%20your%20function%20app%20in%20the%20Azure,then%20select%20Finish%20to%20complete%20your%20deployment%20configuration.) for further explaination